# Чи допустиме в сучасній мові вживання слова "жіночка"?

Tags: етикет, connotation

Раніше мені здавалося, що це слово (якщо так казати про жінку у третій особі) має принаймні нейтральний характер.

СУМ-20 не переглянув своє визначення з часів СУМ-11 і подає [*жіночка*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27169&page=912) лише як:

> Зменш.-пестл. до жі́нка

Згодом я наштовхнувся на [допис Ірини Славінської](https://www.facebook.com/iryna.slavinska/posts/10208735320432698):

> "Ця жіночка", - назвав мене в Палаці мистецтв якийсь мущінка з черги по браслети для акредитованих журналістів <...>

з якого стало зрозуміло, що феміністки розцінюють це слово як зневажливе.

Підтвердження цьому знаходимо і на сайті «Повага» у розділі «[Як уникати сексизму?](http://povaha.org.ua/pobachyly-seksyzm-kudy-zvertatys/)»:

> По-друге, доцільно уникати використання нетолерантних і недоречних слів. Жінки й чоловіки – найбільш прийнятні назви; <...> слово «жіночки» або «жіноцтво» теж видається не зовсім доцільним (якщо співставити із «чоловічками» і «чоловіцтвом»).

І я вже був погодився з тим, що в сучасній мові це слово набуло негативного відтінку, але буквально на цьому тижні вже двічі чую *жіночка* від молодих дівчат.

Збиває з пантелику і те, що на самому сайті «Повага» це слово також вживається:

> Я стояла в черзі до гейту, а позаду мене – літня жінка і чоловік. І, коли дійшла моя черга, то бабця сказала: «Жіночко, а пропустіть цього мужчину». [[1]](http://povaha.org.ua/seksyzm-ne-zhart-ale-nad-nym-tezh-mozhna-smiyatysya-ukrajinski-pysmennytsi-pro-simyu-robotu-ta-stereotypy/)
>
> Я фактично з тим самим зустрілася в Києві, коли 1 січня спускалася вигулювати собаку – наш ліфт зупиняється, коли йде вниз, і одна жіночка сильно засмутилася, бо  першим розраховувала побачити чоловіка, а побачила – мене [[2]](http://longread.povaha.org.ua/natalka-snyadanko-seksyzm-i-robota-tse-vzagali-zvuchyt-yak-synonimy/)

Чи є образливим вживання чоловіком *жіночка* щодо третьої особи? Вживання жінкою? Якщо так, які відповідники нейтрального відтінку слід обрати?

Comment: Нормальне звертання, іноді дивишся на особу жіночої статі та розумієш, що язик не повертається звернутися до неї "пані", а "жіночко" як раз))


А посилання на Славінську маячня, вона ставить на шальки терез українське слово "жіночка" та якийсь недолугий покруч "мущінка "

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, що однозначного значення чи сприйняття цього звернення не має. З мого досвіду, звернення *жіночко* може мати як позитивний так і негативний відтінок, залежно від ситуації. Наприклад, в Чернігівській області, коли чоловік або жінка звертається до *жіночки* приблизно одного віку, то це зазвичай сприймається позитивно, але якщо "жіночко" звучатиме від юнака або дівиці в адресу дорослої жінки, то це вже може жінці не сподобатися. Тому, думаю, що не бажано говорити *жіночко* особі яка значно старша за вас.